# AI .PNG not exporting a black background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, background, black

When exporting my illustrator file as a .png and choosing to export with a black background transparency, it exports with a white background. I have tried one with artboards and one without, but to no avail. Help?

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "with a black background transparency"?  I don't quite understand that.  Can you perhaps edit your question to clarify.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check here for exporting options.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/exporting-artwork.html

In the export options, under preview, select "Black" for "Background Color"

[image]